# Invalid MEX-file error in MATLAB using GPUstart

Tags: matlab, cuda

I get following error with run GPUstart in Matlab:

```
Error using ==> moduleinit at 14
Invalid MEX-file 'C:\GPUmat\modules\rand\RANDModuleManager.mexw64': The
specified module could not be found.

Error in ==> GPUmatLoadModules at 18
      moduleinit;

Error in ==> GPUstart at 168
GPUmatLoadModules(fullfile(GPUmatPath,'modules'));
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar problem in google, maybe it will help you:

http://www.mathworks.de/support/solutions/en/data/1-X8A09/index.html

> Subject:
>
> Why do I receive a "specified module could not be found" error while
>   running a MEX-file created from MATLAB 7.0.1 (R14SP1)? Problem
>   Description:
>
> When I try to run a MEX-file I created, I receive the following error:
>   ??? Invalid MEX-file 'MEX-file name': The specified module could not
>   be found. where "MEX-file name" is the name of my MEX-file. However, I
>   did not receive any errors when compiling the file.
>
> Solution:
>
> This error can occur if you do not have all of the necessary DLL files
>   that the MEX-function is dependent upon or if you are running a
>   MEX-file on a different version of MATLAB than it was compiled on.
>
> In order to view dependent DLL files and help locate the source of
>   this error, you may use the third-party product "Dependency Walker".
>   The Dependency Walker can be downloaded from the following web site:
>
> http://www.dependencywalker.com/
>
> Kindly refer to the attached solutioon below for more information on
>   how to use the Dependency Walker to profile your MEX file.
>
> After finding the missing dependent module, add it to the directory
>   where the MEX file resides or add it to the system search path.